# Any way to get Context value in component constructor method in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way to get and handle a context value in another place except `render` method like `constructor` or a custom function that I declared in my component class?

In a way that I know, the consumer tag surrounds the fetch function but, I don't want to handle value in consumer tag.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate, the linked question asks  how to get context in *lifecycle callbacks*, while this one asks about getting it in the *constructor*. The approach proposed in the accepted answer doesn't work for constructor.

Comment: yes you can use ```     constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context) 
// this.context
}

Answer (score 19):

This is possible, You may use like

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
 }
```

Comment: This form is deprecated

Comment: @gman So what are you supposed to do instead?

Comment: The new context API is given here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: how I can access context in the functional component

Answer (score 3):

```
constructor(props, context) {
super(props);
// do what you want with context
console.log(context);
}
```